# mysql full text search: MATCH without AGAINST?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to debug some code I inherited from another team, to whom I have no access.

The code is generating the following query:

```
SELECT blah FROM missing_table 
WHERE ... 
AND MATCH ('@identity PROFILE @security 0|10000060') 
GROUP BY document_id ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Note the lack of an "AGAINST" clause.

This query is generating the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''@identity PROFILE @security 0|10000060')

A couple of odd things here:

1) The table (I've changed the name to "missing_table" here to protect the innocent) doesn't show up when I do a "desc" or "show tables".

2) There is no "AGAINST" clause in the query.

Any clues about what might be going on here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You only said clues, so a little unclear on what I would do if I couldn't find the table definition at least , if not the data. but here's an example of a working query that I use to search across three columns;  MM, address1, and city , in maintable.
(I thought you had to comma separate everything, but seeing more and more beginners getting away with murder and it working with mysql statements.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `maintable` where `type` = '" .  $ptyp . "'  AND MATCH(MM, address1, city) AGAINST('" . $one . "*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  LIMIT " . $pagelimit. ", 20";
```